# Need for std::decay in noexcept operator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, noexcept

The following code requires using `std::decay` inside `noexcept operator` in *gcc*, but not in *clang*.

```
template<typename... Ts>
class B;

template<typename T>
class B<T> {
    T t;
public:
    template<typename U>
    constexpr B(U&& t)
    // without decay - strange behavior in gcc, see main below  <===
    noexcept(noexcept(T{std::forward<U>(t)}))
        // if adding decay - all cases in main are ok with both gcc and clang
        // noexcept(noexcept(std::decay_t<T>{std::forward<U>(t)}))
    : t(std::forward<U>(t)) {}
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
class B<T, Ts...>: protected B<Ts...> {
public:
    template<typename U, typename... Us>
    constexpr B(U&& t, Us&&... ts)
        : B<Ts...>{std::forward<Us>(ts)...} {}
};

template<typename... Ts>
constexpr auto create(Ts&&... ts) {
    return B<Ts...>{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...};
}

template<typename... Ts>
B(Ts...) -> B<Ts...>;
```

### main

```
int main() {
    // ok in both gcc and clang:
    // [1] the "hello" parameter is not last
    auto b1 = create("hello", 1); 
    auto b2 = create(1, "hello", 5);
    // [2] passing it directly to the ctor of B
    B b3(1, "hello");

    // fails with gcc when the noexcept doesn't use decay
    // but only if "hello" is the last argument and passed via a function
    auto b4 = create(1, "hello");
    auto b5 = create("hello");
}
```

The compilation error by gcc is:

```
<source>:13:40: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' 
         [-fpermissive]

   13 |     noexcept(noexcept(T{std::forward<U>(t)}))
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
      |                                        |
      |                                        const char*
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/s7rf64

Any idea for this strange behavior? Is it a gcc bug? or is `std::decay` indeed required?

Comment: Dropping brace initialization [fixes the issue](https://godbolt.org/z/dKacbG). Looks like `gcc` expect list of char values in case of brace initialization. IMO this gcc bug, but language layer is needed for that.

Comment: Obviously, the gcc compiler treats "hello" as an array of char's. Try to compile with options -Wall -Wextra.

Comment: @B0FEE664 every C/C++ compiler does that since this is a type of string literals.

Comment: `template<typename U> B(U&&)` is "dangerous" as it also takes `B(B&)` where copy constructor is expected...

Comment: @Jarod42 that's right, but for the sake of minimizing the example all other constructors as well as `std::enable_if` restrictions which do not affect the question were removed.

Comment: `template<typename U> B(SomeTag, U&&)` is an easy fix for small example (and possibly for real too). but even if you know caveat of your code, warn future readers seems important too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the remark by @Marek R it seems to be a bug in gcc.

[A bug was opened on gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96936).

The following case also fails with gcc and not with clang:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto convert(U&& t) {
    // fails on gcc:
    return T{std::forward<U>(t)};
    // works ok if it is not brace initialization:
    // return T(std::forward<U>(t));
}

template<std::size_t INDEX, typename T, typename U, typename... Us>
auto convert(U&& t, Us&&... ts) {
    if constexpr(INDEX == 0) {
        return convert<U>(t);
        // works well if we add decay
        // return convert<std::decay_t<U>>(t);
    }
    else {
        return convert<INDEX-1, T>(ts...);
    }
}

int main() {
    // fails with gcc
    auto p = convert<1, const char*>(1, "hello");
}
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/jqxbfj